# Why in starting it opens suddenly without animation effect?

Tags: animation

When i unlock my iphone by finger print or pass code it opens suddenly like in a second without any animation 
I want to ask why this is happen?

Answer (score 1):

You've probably (accidentally) turned off the animation effect.

**How to do enable animations without jailbreaking**

- Open `Settings → General → Accessibility`
- Make sure `Remove Motion` is set to `Off`